# Can $BPP \subset P/poly$ be strengthened to a single infinitely long advice?

Tags: random, computational-complexity

It is well known that $BPP \subset P/poly$, by probabilistic method.

Can this be strengthened: Is there a single string $a \in \{0,1\}^{\omega}$ such that there's a polynomial time deterministic Turing machine with $a$ written on separate tape that works on every input from $BPP$ in polynomial time? (This resembles König lemma a bit.)

Comment: There was an issue with merging your accounts that the SE developers will have to take care of, so I can't do it right now unfortunately.

Comment: Your accounts have been merged! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose a language $L$ is accepted by a machine $M$ with polynomial advice $\alpha : n \mapsto \{ 0,1 \}^{\mathrm{poly}(n)}$. Then define $a \in \{0,1\}^{\omega}$ to be the infinite concatenation $\langle \alpha_0, \alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_n, \ldots \rangle$. This works as a single advice string for any input of arbitrary length.

Why? On an input of length $n$, we simply read the prefix of $a$ consisting of the first $n+1$ "blocks" $\langle \alpha_0, \alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n \rangle$, and then extract the string $\alpha_n$. This lets us simulate $M$ on the given input with advice $\alpha_n$, and we are done.

We also need to keep track of the length of the prefix we read. This is equal to 
$$
|\alpha_0|+|\alpha_1|+\ldots+|\alpha_n| \leq (n+1) |\alpha_n| = O(n) \times \mathrm{poly}(n),
$$ 
which is, in turn, polynomially bounded. We are, of course, assuming (reasonably) that the length of the advice is a monotonically increasing function of the input length.

Comment: Oops, now I am embarrassed. I somehow ended up in this question, and answered it without checking the date. Sorry for bumping up a really old question...

Comment: It is completely fine (even encouraged) to bump up old question by answering them. :)

Comment: Thank you - so it is not limited to $BPP$. The question was created by an old account of mine, if they will be merged I'll mark as accepted.